# I change one document css and change all tags "p" (CSS + ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How I may change the tag 'p' on this page without change tag 'p' on others pages?

In home page I have outhers components with tag p and this component changes whem I change the document CardSlick.css, But the name of document on home page is loginPage.css.

Someone knows how help me?

Thanks for attention!!

ReactJS Code:

```
CardIndividual() {
    return this.state.card.map( card =>   
        { 
        return (
            <div className={'background'}>
                <div className={'contentCard'}>
                    <div className={'titleStyle'}>
                        <h>{card.title}</h>
                    </div>  
                    <div className={'maxText'}>
                        <p>
                            {card.description_challenge}                             
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className={'details'}>
                        <Button variant="secondary">detalhes</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid py-2">
            <div className="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
                    {this.CardIndividual()}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CSS code:

```
p {
width: 15vw;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-lines: 5;}
```

Comment: use the selector: .contentCard p {...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying styles to tag, provide style to it's id or class.